# What should I check in git config for a path that has been ignored until now?

Tags: git, macos, gitignore

.DS_Store files have been ignored for over 3 years

.DS_Store file has begun listing in "git status" as modified.

~/.gitignore_global has entry .DS_Store

.gitconfig has listing core.excludesfile=/Users//.gitignore_global

git check-ignore -v -n .DS_Store
output > :: .DS_Store

brew upgrade git

macOS 11.7 git 2.38.1

git user 8+ years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your `git config` or `gitignore`.

Git's `gitignore` rules affect only files that do not *already* exist in the index. Therefore, *.DS_Store* must be appearing in your `git status` because someone added and committed it, and you now have that commit (or a descendant commit) checked out.

So to make Git stop showing it in status, you need to remove it from the index. You can do that with `git rm --cached ...`

Comment: Another similar explanation is that it is tracked even if it was ignored (say... the file was added/committed.... then a rule to ignore it was added.... or it was ignored and then for-added/committed). It could have been like that for years without anyone noticing because the file has not been modified... but if it is modified recently, BAM!

Comment: @eftshift0 That's actually the same explanation. I didn't say anything about _when_ someone added and committed it. :)

Comment: quick & helpful thank you